# Response code 400 with Paypal

Tags: paypal

I have a problem. What does the following error mean?

```html
[03-06-2016 06:39:03] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection: INFO : Response Status  : 201
[03-06-2016 06:39:46] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection: INFO : POST //api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token
[03-06-2016 06:39:47] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection: INFO : Response Status  : 200
[03-06-2016 06:39:47] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection: INFO : GET //api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-6H11042662505992DK5I45RY
[03-06-2016 06:39:48] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection: INFO : Response Status  : 200
[03-06-2016 06:39:48] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection: INFO : PATCH //api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-6H11042662505992DK5I45RY
[03-06-2016 06:39:49] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection: INFO : Response Status  : 200
[03-06-2016 06:39:49] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection: INFO : POST //api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token
[03-06-2016 06:39:50] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection: INFO : Response Status  : 200
[03-06-2016 06:39:50] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection: INFO : GET //api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-6H11042662505992DK5I45RY
[03-06-2016 06:39:51] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection: INFO : Response Status  : 200
[03-06-2016 06:39:51] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection: INFO : POST //api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-6H11042662505992DK5I45RY/execute
[03-06-2016 06:39:52] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection: INFO : Response Status  : 400
[03-06-2016 06:39:52] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection: ERROR : Got Http response code 400 when accessing //api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-6H11042662505992DK5I45RY/execute. {"name":"PAYMENT_NOT_APPROVED_FOR_EXECUTION","message":"Payer has not approved payment","information_link":"//developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#PAYMENT_NOT_APPROVED_FOR_EXECUTION","debug_id":"dbfc0523997d7"}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can [only execute a Payment that has been approved by the customer](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#payment_execute).

In order to check if a Payment is approved [look it up](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#payment_get) and ensure that the value of it's `state` property is `"approved"`.